# How to navigate to another UIView controller (previously created in storyboard) by pressing an image

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, navigation

I have created an image in my current story board and then I added the tap gesture to it so now once it's been tapped I know . Then I've created an other UIView controller in my story board which is connected to the cocatoch class called "DetailedUIViewController.swift" . Now I want to move to that view once I clicked on my image .

Here is my image :

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalEnergy: UIImageView!
```

and here is my tap gesture definition :

```
    let TGTE = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(totalEnergyFunc))
    totalEnergy.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    TGTE.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    totalEnergy.addGestureRecognizer(TGTE)
```

and here is the function that get called once I click on the image :

```
   func totalEnergyFunc(){

}
```

Now what I am trying to get is how to move to the second view which is previously created once my function get called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a `storyboard ID` for `DetailedUIViewController`

Press Command + Option + 3 and set `storyboard ID` for `DetailedUIViewController`

[image: storyboard ID]

Present `DetailedUIViewController` in `totalEnergyFunc` method

```
func totalEnergyFunc(){
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```